# Creating a smoothly-sloping boundary (a 'lunch tray' effect) in the Z axis with CSS

Tags: css

I want to create an element with a 3D-like effect: it should appear to recess into the background.

Throughout this question I'm going to be referring to the Z-axis diagrams from https://neumorphism.io.

Most CSS for 'sunken' elements I've seen create a hard boundary between the sunken area and the non-sunken area. For example using an inset box-shadow:

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 10px #bbb;
  background-color: #bbb1;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello!</div>
```

Using neumorphism.io's Z-axis diagram, the above would look like this:

[image: diagram]

The vertical lines represent a hard visual boundary between the inside and the outside of the element.

By adding a further shadow on the outside of the element, I can smooth the top edges of the Z-axis diagram:

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 10px #bbb, 0px -3px 10px #bbb;
  background-color: #bbb1;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello!</div>
```

The above is represented by the following:

[image: smoother diagram]

That's not quite what I'm going for, though, because those hard edges are still present (and in fact the element is starting to resemble a 3D object placed onto the page and lit from below rather than a 3D recession).

My ideal element should resemble a lunch tray [(image)](https://i.redd.it/wncweudgq4o01.jpg), with the recession creating 3D space for other objects to be in, and would be represented by the following:

[image: very smooth diagram]

Is it possible to create an element with this sort of boundary differential in CSS?

---

I'm well aware of the concerns surrounding the neumorphism style, especially those regarding contrast. In this case that's not a problem - I want to use this style to create a recession for higher-contrast elements to sit in.

Comment: Does any of [these search results](//www.google.com/search?q=css+curved+tab+shape&tbm=isch) help? Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create the Firefox tab using CSS ?](/q/33376922/4642212).

Comment: Hi @SebastianSimon, no, the results you've linked refer to curves in the X and Y axes. I am discussing curves in the Z axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize the box-shadows on positioned pseudo elements to get close to what I think you're looking for:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%; font-family: Arial;
}
body, div {
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  background-color: #ddc;
}
body::before, body::after, div {
  content: ''; position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  width: 5rem; height: 5rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.25 );
}
div {
  z-index: 1; box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 1rem 1rem #ddc;  
  background-color: #ddc; color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.05 );  
  font-size: 2rem; font-weight: bold;
}
div::after {
  content: 'x'; transform: scaleY( 0.875 );
}
body::before {
  transform: translate( -0.5rem, -0.5rem );
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 1rem 0.5rem rgba( 0,0,0,0.5 );
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.5 );    
}
body::after {
  transform: translate( 0.5rem, 0.5rem );
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 1rem 0.5rem #fff; background-color: #fff;    
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The issue you appear to be having is blurring the edges of the shadow and highlight sections. Making these sections elements themselves and then adding box-shadows directly to them creates a 'feather' effect softening the edges.

You should be able to scale this down to your projects needs.

Comment: Wow - this is perfect. What a stroke of genius!